Simplify a google sheets formula so i don't have to do it column by column
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", A2:A7)),
FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A7, "[0-9]+"), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", A2:A7))) & " " & A$1,
IF(
  ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", B2:B7)),
  FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B7, "[0-9]+"), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", B2:B7))) & " " & B$1,
  IF(
    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", C2:C7)),
    FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C7, "[0-9]+"), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LST", C2:C7))) & " " & C$1,
    "" 
))))

I have this formula and need to make it so I don't have to do it column by column and just do A2:7

This would be better-suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com

you can directly write A2:C7 without the repentance it iterates through each cell and checks "LST" text

the & A$1, wouldn't work. I need to put A1 next to the number that gets extracted when in the a column and B1 when a number from the b column gets extracted
